# Service EndPoint Life Cycle in Rest

Tags: rest

Let say I have student class

```
@Path("/student")
public class Student {
    private List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Path("/update")
    public void update(){
       list.add("xyx");
    }


}
```

Now whenever a call to localhost:8080/student/update is made, same list object will be used or a new object will be recreated in every request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It wont be recreated it will only add.  Is this a trick question?

You should try your questions first.